# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: using RestEASY, Intellij IDEA 16.1, Tomcat 8.0.33

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, intellij-idea, resteasy

It have been asked a lot questions kind of this, but I have tried all suggested variants, googled my problem, checked RestEASY specification. Nothing helped me. 
I am creating a very simple kind of "Hello World" application. And when I am writing the  URL that routes to my REST Service, I receive the following error and the blank, empty page in my browser.

**This is the stack trace:**

```
15-May-2016 14:41:58.977 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleWebApplicationException RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute
 javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/status
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:75)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:194)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**This is my pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.taras.resty</groupId>
    <artifactId>Resty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**This is my web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>V1_Status</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.taras.resty.status.V1_Status</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>V1_Status</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**And this is my class that handles my REST requests:**

```
package com.taras.resty.status;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/v1/status")
public class V1_Status extends Application  {
    private static final String api_version= "00.01.00";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle(){
        return "<p>Java Web Service</p>";
    }

    @Path("/version")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnVersion(){
        return "<p>Version + </p>" + api_version;
    }

}
```

The URL that I am using is : http://localhost:8080/api/v1/status

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT - SOLVED**  For people who will face the same problem. @tair helped me a lot in solving my bug. just try his version (you can find it here https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/hello-jaxrs). 
We haven't found the reason, it has disappered  somehow(magic).
And of course for more detailed information look into the specification 
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e113

Comment: Don't you also need a `javax.ws.rs.Application` subclass with `@ApplicationPath`?

Comment: @tair you mean one more class, and to mark this class with the  `@ApplicationPath` annotation ? I have tried this variant as well, didn't work for me(

Comment: Didn't you forget the application context in the URL?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin what do you mean? haven't understood exactly the question

Comment: @TyLeR Cassio is right, your url must be something like http://localhost:8080/yourapp/api/v1/status

Comment: @TyLeR oh sorry, probably we are wrong, as your stack trace clearly states that the request is handled by resteasy

Comment: @tair yeap. hasn't worked either

Comment: @TyLeR I read your V1_Status carefully: you must have _separate_ `Application` subclass + a class for Rest API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your web.xml suggests you are using a Servlets 3.1 compatible Tomcat, the configuration for Resteasy should be different. Please, refer to section `3.5. Standalone Resteasy in Servlet 3.0 Containers`  of official Resteasy documentation [1].

If you insist on the old style configuration, you should specify your JAX-RS application as `init-param` for `HttpServletDispatcher`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.taras.resty.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>V1_Status</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/api</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**In either case you have to subclass `javax.ws.rs.Application`.**

UPDATE: Here [2] is a complete application example. Tested with Tomcat 8.0.33

[1] http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e113

[2] https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/hello-jaxrs

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I have checked my Servlet version, and yeah, it's older than 3.0. so i have edited my `web.xml` and `V1_Status` class. but it still doen't work. would you be so kind to take a look one more time? thank you

Comment: @TyLeR please try the updated web.xml fragment. I added context-param per documentation

Comment: sad to say, but no. nothing has changed

Comment: @TyLeR why don't you want to use Servlet 3.0 features? Tomcat 8.0 supports it.

Comment: i have installed Tomcat version 8.0.33, this version of Tomcat uses Servlets ver. older than 3.0. okey, I will try tomorrow to install Tomcat younger version with younger version of Servlets. and will try to use `resteasy-servlet-initializer` the way that is written in the offcial documentation that you linked me. maybe it will work

Comment: @TyLeR your link also says Tomcat 8.0 supports Servlets 3.1.

Comment: 3.1>3.0 Quatation taken from document "The `resteasy-servlet-initializer` artifact will not work in Servlet versions older than 3.0."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112002/discussion-between-tair-and-tyler).

Comment: are you here? can we continue our conversation in chat? I have one more question